# How to override NumberFormatter string and number methods

Tags: ios, swift

[NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) has a couple methods, `number` and `string` which seem to imply they are responsible for converting the value to and from each type. However, when trying to override these methods I can't get them to fire.. (the print statements are never seen).

Am I missing something? The only progress I made was with the `getObjectValue(_:for:range:)` method in setting the numerical value, but never the string.

import SwiftUI

```
class NumberProxy : NumberFormatter {
    override func string(from number: NSNumber) -> String? {
        print("hello from", number)
        return "HELLO!"
    }

    override func number(from string: String) -> NSNumber? {
        print("to number...", string)
        return NSNumber(value: 123)
    }
    
//    override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, range rangep: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange>?) throws {
//        try super.getObjectValue(obj, for: string, range: rangep)
//        print(obj)
//        obj?.pointee = NSNumber(value: 4.0) // this worked
//    }
}

struct Test: View {
    @State private var myNumber: Int = 0
            
    var body : some View {
        TextField("Current Balance", value: $myNumber, formatter: NumberProxy())
                
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to override these? That's very unusual.

Comment: I want to store my numbers as `Int` but let the user enter them as `23.34` (for dollar values).

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a `Currency` struct, to wrap your int. Then you can just write an extension on `NumberFormatter` that takes a `Currency` and returns a `String`. Subclassing like this is really weird and fragile

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this platform and not sure about best practices. I will look into that too.

Comment: I recommend that when ever asking "why doesn't X work", you also state your motiviation behind X. Otherwise, the answers you'll get are just superficial patchwork to get X working, without question whether X is a sane approach for your solution. That's called an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The real question to ask here is: "How do I format an `Int` of cents as a currency?"

Comment: This is a pretty standard best practice these days. Inheritance has a *lot* of down sides, and you can almost always achieve the same goals in better ways. In this case, you don't want to create a new special version of `NumberFormatter`, you just want to use a typical old `NumberFormatter` in a particular way. Using `Int`s in a data model to model pretty much anything besides a count of something (even then, it might not be appropriate, like for currency) is usually a bad idea. This is called primitive obsession https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alexander-ReinstateMonica. I'd like make it as simple as `var cashMoney: Currency = 12` but I don't see anything jumping out at me on https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216900/discussion-between-speg-and-alexander-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 2):

What you need to override is `Formatter`'s `string(for:)` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter/1415993-string):

```
override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
```

---

```
class NumberProxy: NumberFormatter {
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        guard let value = (obj as? NSNumber)?.intValue else { return nil }
        return .init(value)
    }
}
```

---

```
let number = NSNumber(value: 123.456)

let string = NumberProxy().string(from: number)  // "123"
```

edit/update:

To input Double as integers:

```
override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, range rangep: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRange>?) throws {
    try super.getObjectValue(obj, for: string, range: rangep)
    obj?.pointee = Int(string.filter(\.isWholeNumber)) as AnyObject?
}
```

---

```
let integer = NumberProxy().number(from: "123.45")!.intValue  // 12345
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Why doesn't that one show up when you go to view the definition, or in the docs?

Comment: `string(for:)` is a `Formatter`'s class instance method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter